# generating four digits by using the C++ randint

Tags: c++, random

I am using the header file [`std_lib_facilities.h`](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) while studying Stroustrup's book "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++"
and I'm in the early chapters. In the exercise 13 of chapter 5 I got familiar with randint() function for making my "Cows and Bulls" game(the previous exercise) a bit more interesting, but when I use this function, it sometimes produces more digits than the number of times I iterate my loop.

From [`std_lib_facilities.h`](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h):

```
inline int randint(int max) { return rand()%max; }
```

And here is my code:

```
vector<int> answer;
for (int i = 0; i<4; ++i) { 
    int answer_digit=randint(10);
    answer.push_back(answer_digit); 
}
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) std::cout << answer[i];
_getch();
std::cout << std::endl;
```

for instance in my case it gives 63109 for the first number, and then 4706 , then 5423 and then 7 more four-digit numbers and then again a five-digit one which is 94410. Why is that happening? Is that an error from the function in the library or it's just a silly mistake in my own code? Thanks.

(I know I could get a more realistic random by using a seed, but that's not related to my question(at least, my guess!)).

Comment: You may want to update to a later version of the book. Stroustrup's code is dated from 2010, which was before the `<random>` header was added to C++, and `<random>` should be the baseline API you use for generating random numbers, to prevent issues exactly like what you're facing here.

Comment: Try printing a space between the numbers to see how many there are and what values. It looks like one of them may be 10, but I don't see why that would happen.

Comment: It seems obvious that randint return a number on 0-N rather than 0-N-1. All the five digit examples contain 10.

Comment: @interjay I changed that 10 to 9 and now the issue is resolved, I wonder why he suggests the readers to use 10 in calling that function! Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @M-J If the function you have is the same one as in the file you linked, then it returns `rand()%max` which should never return 10 for `max == 10`. So the book is correct but maybe you have another issue somewhere.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean The linked implementation of `randint` can only return 0 to n-1.

Comment: @interjay I can put my whole code somewhere. if you want to take a look at? This is weird.

Comment: Another problem still remains in this exercise! when I use seeding, which is some digits are generated twice, and it's illegal in "Bulls and Cows" game AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate 4 digits without repeats, random shuffle an array of 10 0 -9 and take the first four.

To random shuffle, swap the first with a random index on 0 to N-1 (so possibly a no-op swapping with itself) swap the second on 1 to N-1, the third of 2 to N-1 and so on. If leading 0 is disallowed, special case the first digit.